# Unauthorized credit card payment

Tags: exploit, credit-card

I have a debit card which links to my savings account in a let's call it Bank A. I had never used it for online purchases/transactions (not even interbank transfer). After a while, I purchased virtual credit into my online wallet from an online gaming platform. During the purchase I had to provide my debit card details (number, CVC, expiry date) without authentication. Normally I will receive TAC to confirm the transaction but in this case I did not.

A few days later, I was called by Bank A saying my debit card was frozen due to suspicious transactions (amounted to roughly RM 1xxx) but failed to process due to I had only RM 2xx in my bank account.

Now I am afraid that websites might use my bank details to perform purchases. Will this be the case? Is it true?

Comment: Being skeptical because from what I thought websites will not reveal the identification of the credit card details even to the web developer. I could say I am confuse of what I had experienced. I trusted Bank A and that particular gaming platform.

Comment: Sorry it is the other way round. I believe websites will not abuse but it looks like it had happened. For example I use my debit card for online purchase today and the same card was compromised the next day. I think it is not coincidence.

Comment: Other than already clarified language problems, there's not much to be written as an answer: **you should immediately report it to the bank and get a new card with new details**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: Report that your card has been compromised to your bank and ask for a new one.**

You are the victim of a [credit card fraud.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card_fraud) Your bank (Bank A) noticed a suspicious activity with your debit card and froze it.

As [techraf](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/86652/techraf) said, report that this activity was indeed fraudulent to your bank. If some unauthorized transactions were approved, you can reclaim your money. Your bank will send you a new credit/debit card.

As soon as the card is frozen, nobody is able to use your card details anymore. Your new card will have new details, thus you won't have to worry about the previous one being compromised. It won't affect the new one.

We can't tell how your current card has been compromised. Perhaps the website is not as trustful as you though, or perhaps something else happened, like:

- Someone saw your card and wrote down the relevant information;
- The website uses HTTP to transmit your card details to the server;
- Your computer is compromised;
- An in store credit card database leaked
- …

Comment: I update my McAfee Antivirus definition from time to time. It was the least I would suspect. Anyway no money was lost but I've learnt something FOC.

Comment: @Yuriko: Do you mean `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS`?

Comment: @hamena314 : Yeah, my bad; AstroDan corrected this!